# Apache 404 error on localhost

Tags: coldfusion

I am experiencing some weird problem. I have bunch of sites on my localhost.

I can hit this page:

```
 http://localhost:8500/site1/index.cfm.
```

Under site1, i have css, images and scripts folders. For example:

C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\site1\css\styles.css

When I go to :

```
http://localhost:8500/site1/css/styles.css,
```

I get an 404 error from Apache.

Why?

Comment: You misspelled "styles" in hour http link. If that's not the issue (*i.e.*, it still fails after fixing the typo) then it might be a directory permissions issue or http config issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @mbratch. yes, it was folder permissions. thanks

Comment: Technically is this an Apache question? 8500 is the default for the CF "built in" server. I suspect that is the server throwing the error.

Comment: @falconseye - you should add your solution as an answer to your own question so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your directory permissions. Make sure the sub-directory has at least "read" permissions.